# Indexing large data set with lucene.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco, lucene.net, examine

I am indexing 23,000 records from a sqlserver table using a lucene wrapper called examine (Its an umbraco .net cms website that has something called examine which is abstraction around lucene.net).

On my dev server which runs with 4 cores it takes about 11 mins and all works fine. On my live server which has 8 cores it seems to take forever i started it this morning and it seems to still be going.  I recently came across this document related to lucene.net and large indexes and cpu cores see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/micl/archive/2014/06/21/reduce-cpu-core-count-to-improve-lucene-net-index-building-performance.aspx has anyone else had this issue?

Regards

Ismail

Comment: Possibly not what you want to hear, but have you considered an alternative? I am using ElasticSearch (is free and runs as a service) with Nest and I just reduced my indexing time of around 20k records to about 20 seconds. I'm sure it could be improved upon too.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that the data was raw SQL, not Umbraco nodes. 23k nodes could be a killer!

Comment: Digbyswift, big fan of elastic unfortunately site is live so no time to add that and now its no longer live! Thanks for the suggestion, we have though pin pointed issue to app restarts and they were triggering re indexing so not really examine.